# Prove this modular congruency?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove that $2^{2x} \equiv 1 \mod 3$ for any integer $x$?. I know this is true but is there a nice way to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:-**

An approach which does not involve modular arithmetic.

R.T.P.

$2^{2x} \equiv 1 \mod 3$

or,$2^{2x}-1$ is divisible by $3$.

Now,$2^{2x}=4^x$

So,prove by induction now that $4^x-1$ is divisible by $3.$.'

Comment: i feel silly... $4^{x+1}  = 4(3n + 1)$ therefore $\frac{4^{x+1} - 1}{3} = 4n + 1$. and it works for x = 1. thanks for a simpler method

Comment: @gebra-Welcome....nice problem though...

Answer (score 4):

Its very simple.
$$2^{2x}=4^x\equiv 1^x (\text{mod } 3)\equiv 1(\text{mod } 3).$$